# How to set parameters in XSL stylesheet with the help of Transformer object when i have my xml generated dynamically in jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xslt, transformer-model

I need to set Parameters in my XSL stylesheet.I am retrieving all values in a list and using it to create XML dynamically in jsp. So there is no external  xml file created in this process..But now I need to set variable in XSLt stylesheet.  But as there is no xml file created so I am finding it difficult to use transform Object.Here  is MY code

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList,aj.model.BriefBoardDetail,
     javax.xml.transform.Transformer,javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory,
       javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource" %>
     <% ArrayList<BriefBoardDetail> list =(ArrayList)
       request.getAttribute("boardList"); 
       int countofPages =(Integer) request.getAttribute("countOfPages");
      int pageNumber = (Integer) request.getAttribute("currentPageNumber");
     Transformer transformer =  
               TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new 
  StreamSource("/xslt/indexPageStyle.xsl"));
     transformer.setParameter("currentPage" , pageNumber);
     transformer.setParameter("lastPage" , countofPages);
     transformer.transform(???, ???);//what parameter i need to set here?
   %> 
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt/indexPageStyle.xsl"    
    version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8" ?> 
   <AlgorithmHome>
    <%
    for(BriefBoardDetail bbs : list) {
     %>
    <subject id = '<%=bbs.getBoardId() %>' >
      <name> <%= 
       bbs.getBoardName() %></name>
       <description> <%= 
       bbs.getDescription() %></description>
     </subject>
 <%} %>
</AlgorithmHome>
```

So I need to set countOfPages and pageNumber in indexPageStyle.xsl.But as xml is generated dynamically in this jsp so what I need to set as **XMLSource** and **outputTarget** in transformer.transform(XMLSource, outputTarget) if i need to display it in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in above code and it worked fine..

```
     <%@page contentType ="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
     <%@page import ="java.util.ArrayList,aj.model.BriefBoardDetail" %>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>
      <% ArrayList<BriefBoardDetail> list =(ArrayList) request.getAttribute("boardList"); 
      Integer countofPages =(Integer) request.getAttribute("countOfPages");
      Integer pageNumber = (Integer) request.getAttribute("currentPageNumber");
          %>
    <c:set var="xmldata">
     <AlgorithmHome>
       <%
          for(BriefBoardDetail bbs : list) {
        %>
        <subject id = '<%=bbs.getBoardId()%>'>
         <name> <%= 
                bbs.getBoardName() %></name>
         <description> <%= 
              bbs.getDescription() %></description>
       </subject>
 <%}%>
  </AlgorithmHome>
</c:set>
 <c:import url="/xslt/indexPageStyle.xsl" var="xslt"/>
 <x:transform xml="${xmldata}" xslt="${xslt}">
 <x:param name ="currentPage" value="${param:pageNumber}"/>
 <x:param name ="lastPage" value="${param:countofPages}"/>
</x:transform>
```

Its all working fine.
But now i want to pass both countofPages and pagenumber to my XSL stylesheet.But I am not able to pass it.I google and all i got was everyone passed String inside value tag.I am so confused ..Please tell me hoe to pass a value

Comment: Its now done.I used EL to take value from request attribute and pass it to XSLT..